# jQuery append after using sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can move my lists the way i want, from one UL to another. Everything works perfect! But, one of the lists have a "resize" option, so when i move LI from one UL to another, you can't resize it, cause the UL where the LI was located didn't have a resize attached to it.

```
$("ul").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
}).disableSelection();

$("#newsLayout li").resizable({
    grid: 10
});
```

i know i need to append something (maybe use live?), but my jQuery skills are not that good. Maybe some of you guys could help me out?

Comment: provide more `code`. perhaps the list view with class names and ids?

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the old resizable and create a new one after sortupdate:

```
 $("ul").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    update: function() 
            {
              $("li").resizable('destroy');
              $("#newsLayout li").resizable({grid: 10});}
    }).disableSelection();
```